# Are type definitions for npm packages required only on developer machine?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, visual-studio-code, npm-install

As I understand, the type definition modules (for npm packages) provide intellisense for developers so that they don't have to guess parameter types when calling library methods. For example, these modules are very useful in my typescript project when I consume third party libraries (along with their type definition modules) in my vscode editor.

1. Is this the only purpose (i.e. provide intellisense) in for type definition modules?
2. If the answer is yes, then they should not be required on build servers and production machines. Is this true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are working with plain old JavaScript then yes, type packages are only used to provide IntelliSense and better language support in the editor. In many cases, [automatic type acquisition](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/javascript#_automatic-type-acquisition) should download and manage these typings files for you. You can also list these type packages explicitly in your dev dependencies

If you are working with TypeScript or using the new [`checkJS`](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/javascript#_type-checking-and-quick-fixes-for-javascript-files) feature to typecheck your JavaScript code, the type definitions must be installed on the build machine. Just list them in the dev dependencies. You should generally never need type packages on a production machine